# How to add clear looking / thin text in Paintshop Pro X6

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to add text to an image in PSP X6 and I know how to do it but how can I make it look clearer/thinner?

I've created this using Arial (9 pixels) and the default stroke width (1) and not sure what else to do to make the text look less thick...

[image: previous button with text looking too thick]

Answer (score 0):

As a long-time fellow user of Corel's PaintShop Pro (including several versions by JASC before that), I have experienced the "Text" tool fluctuate (in effectiveness) over the years. This can be quite frustrating - as the quality (crispness in particular) of the text seems to vary from version-to-version.. - and sadly X6 (recently superseded by X7) is no exception.

In answer to your question, I would recommend one of the following solutions:

To get the best result with small text:

1) Ensure that the "Anti-alias" option is set to either "Sharp" or "Off".
2) Double-check that the text is not set to Bold (obvious, I know - but easily missed)
3) If possible, try dark greys (rather than pure black) as this can sometimes seem "softer" around the edges.

If you have already checked and/or tried the above, then another option is to use the technique I have adopted many times over the years - as follows:

1) Create your text (e.g. "Previous") but in a separate document - and purposefully set the text size MUCH larger than you need (e.g. 100 Point - the bigger, the better).

2) "Flatten" that image (ensuring you preserve transparency if you plan to overlay your text on a background other than pure white).

3) Resize the image down to the approximate width you require (e.g. 100 Pixels wide) by using the "Image Resize" option and ensuring that "Resample Using" is ticked/checked - and that "Smart Size" is the option used (the others: Bicubic, Bilinear and Weighted Average can also sometimes deliver better results - a little trial and error might be the order of the day until you get the hang of the technique).

Providing the desired end size is not *too* small, you should find the end results MUCH better than simple typing in at (say..) 9 Point to begin with.

Worth noting that this technique works particularly well for "mid-size" text - but you should also see an improvement for smaller sizes too. So something of a workaround for sure, but it definitely can and does work.